# Simple After And Before Method Interceptor With Byte Buddy

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

In [Byte Buddy tutorial](http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) at the time of this writing, everything is explained but a simple after and before method interceptor is not there as I explained below, am I missing something or tutorial is complex. (See LoggerInterceptor example gives method but not object, ChangingLoggerInterceptor example gives object but not invoked method)

What I wanted to achieve is to call a method of an object after its setter method executions. How can I write an interceptor and use it in Java 6?

```
public class DirtyClass{

private String _sField;
private boolean _bDirty;

public void setField(String sField) {
    _sField = sField;
    //setDirty(true); to be appended after proxying
}
public String getField() {
    return _sField;
}
public void setDirty(boolean bDirty){
    _bDirty = bDirty;
}
public boolean isDirty(){
    return _bDirty;
}
}

DirtyClass d = new ByteBuddy().subclass(DirtyClass.class)...???

d.setField("dirty now");
System.out.println(d.isDirty()); //Expecting true
```

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/37719089/13075 ?

Comment: Tried it as setter interceptor, but getting exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of [...] allows for delegation from  public void ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can implement such a mechanism even without a method delegation as follows:

```
DirtyClass d = new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(DirtyClass.class)
  .method(isSetter().and(not(named("setDirty"))))
  .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE.andThen(
      MethodCall.invoke(DirtyClass.class.getMethod("setDirty", boolean.class))
                .with(true)
  )).make()
  .load(DirtyClass.class.getClassLoader())
  .getLoaded()
  .newInstance();
```

This way, every setter is overridden to first invoke its super method and then to invoke the `setDirty` method with `true` as an argument. The linked example in the comments should however work as well.

An interceptor could look like the following (given that some interface `Dirtiable` is implemented):

```
public class Interceptor {
  public static void getter(@SuperCall Runnable zuper, @This Dirtiable self) {
    zuper.run();
    self.setDirty(true);
  }
}
```

This assumes that the instrumented super class implements the `Dirtiable` interface which can be done using `.implement(Dirtiable.class)` where the method can be implemented to set a field using the `FieldAccessor` implementation.

Comment: OK, that's fine. Could you share an example using an interceptor class  since I plan to invoke different methods and make some other setter filtering?

Comment: I'm unable to write an interceptor class and intercept method myself and couldn't find documentation for complete argument list.

Comment: Thank you for examples. Second example is not applicable in my case if so I would use java's reflection proxy. It seems that first example is the way to go although I didn't like it.